# Performance counters CPU results differ from Azure and Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I use Application Insights(AI) on a REST service in Azure. When I go to Azure Portal and open the web app I choose 'Diagnose And Solve Problems' and 'Metrics per Instance (apps)'.

The graph shows me spikes of 85%-95% CPU. But... when opening AI, there is no sample that exceeds the 35%.

How can this outcome difference be explained ?

See the snapshots below:

[image]

[image]